# How to export wcf service method return value to another wcf service

Tags: wcf

My requirement is, i have one WCF service with a method returning some integer value, this value i want to be used by another WCF service, but do not know how like as we used to pass value from one page to another page using sessions or query strings etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you use the wcf-services in the same process you could just use static variables to transfer the values but I would advise to do so.

I would:

- Refactor the behavior of both wcf-services into seperate classes (or even assemblies)
- call the refactored methods from both services

This way you have a clean "seperation of concern" and can use the methods to generate your integer value without any pain.